# Adding a bunch of assets to a Xamarin Android project without copying

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, assets

I have 300 files in my source tree that I want to include as assets. However, I don't want to have two copies of these assets, one copy in the original part of the source tree, and one copy specifically in the Android project build directory. These assets are shared with other build targets, so it would be a pain to have to change both copies when adding or changing a file.

If I try to put my directory into the Assets folder of the Visual Studio project, Visual Studio just makes a copy of the entire directory tree right there in the project.

Is there a way to get Visual Studio to include a directory tree as assets without having to put a copy of each of these files into the project?

Is there a way to make a custom build step that runs a tool to zip the assets so that they can be one file instead of 300, and automatically update the zip file when the source assets change?